# Working with Named Ranges and Objects

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a range of cells from one workbook to another. However, unfortunately, because of the size of the two workbook I can't have them open at the same time.

So the idea was to do it in two steps:

1) Open `workbook1` save the range from one workbook to a object range and close `workbook1`

2) Open `workbook2` save the range from the object to the range in workbook

But this is not working. Could someone help with the code. Thanks. Sample code below

```
Dim Temp as Range
Workbooks.Open (Model1)
Workbooks(Model1).Activate
Temp = Range("First_Input").Value
Workbook(Model1).Close

Workbooks.Open(Model2)
Workbooks(Model2).Activiate
Range("Second_Input").Value = Temp.Value
```

Comment: Can you define _not working_

Comment: I  don't think I'm prepared to dive into a full solution. But you should look into an ODBC query, depending on how the data is structured you might be able to pull it without opening the file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example below:

- Comments are embedded and works as is (without changes). Try this on a 
  workbooks first with random data.
- The example works for a workbook already open, just alter it for "Opening" a workbook.
- I have used the range address in the example. You can play with this depending on what you want to do.

The below works so should be easy to implement, copy and paste into excel.

```
Public Sub CopyData()


Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim wkb1rng As Range
Dim wkb2rng As Range

'Point to Workbook and Sheet 1
'Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(Model1) ' To Open Workbook
Set wkb1 = Workbooks("Book1") ' If workbook is open already


'Sheets is the Index use String for the sheet name
Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets(1)

' Dont need this if you moving objects directly in and out of memory.
' Workbooks(Model1).Activate

' Point to Range
Set wkb1rng = sht1.Range("First_Input")

' What is the address of the Range
Dim address As String
address = wkb1rng.Cells.address

'Point to Workbook and Sheet 2
Set wkb2 = Workbooks("Book2")

'Sheets is the Index use String for the sheet name
Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets(1)

'I imagine Second_Input should be output?
'Use this only if the data range is exactly the same size
'Set wkb2rng = Range("Second_Output")
'else use this ...
Set wkb2rng = sht2.Range(address)

'Copy data across ...
wkb2rng.Value = wkb1rng.Value

End Sub
```